# security-role-mapping not working with file descriptor

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3, cdi

Using glassfish 3.1.1 for a Java EE6 project the security role mapping as defined in `glassfish-web.xml` has no influence on the 'user - role' mapping.

Calling `request.isUserInRole("USER")` as well as `request.isUserInRole("ADMIN")` always returns `false`.

glassfish-web.xml

```
<glassfish-web-app>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
        <group-name>USER</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Annotating `LoginBean.java` with `@DeclareRoles` as shown below, the roles are assigned as expected.

LoginBean.java

```
...
@DeclareRoles({"ADMIN", "USERS"})
@Named(value = "loginBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable { ...
```

Why do I need the `@DeclareRoles` in `LoginBean.java` in order to get a working 'user - role' mapping for `request.isUserInRole`?

Answer (score 4):

A [similar question on Coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/547984/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/SessionContext-isCallerInRole-security-role-but) cites *17.2.5.3 Declaration of Security Roles Referenced from the Bean’s Code*
 of the [EJB 3.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-mrel-evalu-oth-JSpec/):

> **The Bean Provider is responsible for using the DeclareRoles
>   annotation** or the `security-role-ref` elements of the deployment
>   descriptor to declare all the security role names used in the
>   enterprise bean code. The `DeclareRoles` annotation is specified on a
>   bean class, where it serves to declare roles that may be tested by
>   calling `isCallerInRole` from within the methods of the annotated class.
>   **Declaring the security roles allows the** Bean Provider,
>   **Application Assembler, or Deployer to link these security role names
>   used in the code to the security roles defined for an assembled
>   application.**
>
> [...]
>
> If the `DeclareRoles` annotation is not used, the Bean Provider must
>   use the `security-role-ref` elements of the deployment descriptor to
>   declare the security roles referenced in the code.

(Emphasis mine)

So it's just a simple hint to the Deployer and they don't have to interpret the code to get the list of the used roles. It could be really hard if a developer calls the `isUserInRole()` method with a role name which comes from an other method or from a very complex logic.

This also could be useful (from *17.3 Responsibilities of the Bean Provider and/or Application Assembler*):

> *The main reason for providing the security view of the enterprise
>   beans is to simplify the Deployer’s job. In the absence of a security
>   view of an application, the Deployer needs detailed knowledge of the
>   application in order to deploy the application securely. For example,
>   the Deployer would have to know what each business method does to
>   determine which users can call it. The security view defined by the
>   Bean Provider or Application Assembler presents a more consolidated
>   view to the Deployer, allowing the Deployer to be less familiar with
>   the application.*

(I see that the question is about a web application but I think the reasoning behind is the same and servlet spec isn't so detailed.)

From *Deployer’s Responsibilities: Assignment of Security Roles (17.4.2)*:

> The Deployer assigns principals and/or groups of principals (such as
>   individual users or user groups) used for managing security in the
>   operational environment to the security roles defined by means of the
>   `DeclareRoles` and `RolesAllowed` metadata annotations and/or
>   `security-role` elements of the deployment descriptor.

So, according to the spec the `glassfish-web.xml` is created by the Deployer (not the Bean Provider or Application Assembler) and for the Deployer's work he needs the role names from  "`DeclareRoles` and `RolesAllowed` metadata annotations and/or `security-role` elements of the deployment descriptor."

Comment: >`So, according to the spec the glassfish-web.xml is created by the Deployer` - I know you're just citing the spec, but just think about it; how many projects actually have a "deployer"? Certainly not all of them, and I dare to say not even most of them...

Answer (score 1):

The role-mapping in the glassfish-web.xml translates a Java EE application's security role names into a deployment environments user/group mechanism.  The roles are abstract... and until your application uses a role, the mapping is unnecessary and not consulted.